# Problem constructing where clause to include null/0 values

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have an application where users can take tests (which are composed of questions and answers).

I'm trying to construct a query that returns a count of answers grouped by question, for a specific teacher and test.
The problem is I would like the query to return 0 count for questions with no answers.

#### answers

- id
- question_id
- test_id
- student_id

#### questions

- id

#### teacher_students

- student_id
- teacher_id

#### tests

- id

#### Query

```
   SELECT COUNT(answers.id) AS rcount,
          questions.id 
     FROM "questions"
LEFT JOIN answers ON answers.question_id = questions.id
LEFT JOIN teacher_students ON teacher_students.student_id = answers.student_id
    WHERE (questions.test_id = 1)  
      AND (teacher_students.teacher_id = 1)
 GROUP BY questions.id 
 ORDER BY questions.id
```

#### Output

```
 rcount | question_id 
--------+----
      4 | 1
      2 | 3
```

**Desired Output**

```
 rcount | question_id 
--------+----
      4 | 1
      0 | 2
      2 | 3
      0 | 4
```

If I remove `teacher_students.teacher_id = 1`, the number of questions returned is correct, but the count is not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move the `teacher_students.teacher_id = 1` check from the `WHERE` clause to the joining `ON` clause.

When a condition that refers to a table in the right side of a `LEFT JOIN` is put in the WHERE clause, the LEFT JOIN is cancelled and it acts as an `INNER JOIN`.

```
SELECT count(teacher_students.student_id) AS rcount      <--- changed
     , questions.id 
FROM "questions"
  LEFT JOIN answers 
    ON answers.question_id = questions.id
  LEFT JOIN teacher_students 
    ON teacher_students.student_id = answers.student_id
    AND teacher_students.teacher_id = 1
WHERE questions.test_id = 1

GROUP BY questions.id 
ORDER BY questions.id
```

Comment: Your answer is good. But structurally it is better to leave `ON` clause for joins only. So it's better to do this: `((teacher_students.teacher_id = 1) OR (teacher_students.teacher_id is NULL))` on `WHERE` clause.

Comment: @Karolis: No.  If people are going to use OUTER JOIN syntax, they have to be aware that there is a difference between criteria in the `WHERE` vs criteria in the OUTER JOIN's ON clause.  When using an OUTER JOIN, the WHERE clause criteria is applied *after* the join vs the `ON` clause criteria is applied before the JOIN.  What you advocate can result in a significantly different result set than expected.

Comment: @Karolis *"But structurally it is better"* Would you elaborate on this? I've never given a second thought to adding additional conditions to a join predicate. What are the structural problems inherent in doing so?

Comment: @Karolis: Yes, I agree, your suggestion may be better for making the intention clear for anyone who looks at the code later. Dealing with `OR` conditions is not the best attribute of MySQL optimizer though.

Comment: Thanks, but this query returns inaccurate counts that are for all teachers, not for teacher 1 only

Comment: Zoinks, I should have mentioned I am on Postgres, sorry for any confusion

Comment: @juwiley: I think you need to use `count(teacher_students.student_id)`. See the edit.

Comment: @Karolis: And as @OMG points, it may result in different results than expected, like if there are multiple LEFT JOINs and conditions like the OP's in many of those JOINs.

Comment: @djacobson, @OMG, I think that you have misunderstood me. I was talking about academic SQL query structure. `ON` clause is used for joining conditions and `WHERE` clause is used for filtering. So if possible it's better to keep these rules. But practice and theory are not always best friends. My opinion is to keep the code as clear and academic as possible and use "hacks" just when it's clear that they are really needed.

Comment: @ypercube, the problem is when real NULL and empty NULL have different meanings in some particular case. But it's a sufficient rare situation and even then we can try to solve the problem using different methods.

Comment: To keep the purity of the ON clause specifying join conditions, the way to write it is to change the reference to teacher_students to be a reference to an inline view that filters teacher_students. The planner would treat this just the same as putting the filter condition in the ON clause, but IMHO it would actually provide a clearer picture of what the statement means. But some people see any subquery as "omg! evil inefficient complexity!"